# Could someone explain what this means? #python

Tags: python, list

So i'm looking for sort of a layman/beginner explanation as to what this means:

```
L[i:i+lensub]
```

What does that mean by it's self? by the the way `lensub = len(sublist)` and L is list.

Answer (score 3):

What that code is doing is using [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) to slice `L` from position `i` to `i+lensub`.

The format for slice notation is `[start:stop:step]`.

Below is basic demonstration:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> # Get positions 1 to 3
>>> lst[1:3]
[2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: okay, and does the value of i start at, 0? or 1?

Comment: @user2928929 - `i` will be whatever `i` was defined as in your code.  However, you are right in saying that Python indexes start at 0.